# IPhone, MPMoviePlayerController how to disable zooming when double tap on the screen?

Tags: iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I dissable the strange double tap behaviour when playing movie using MPMoviePlayerController.

The double tap makes zoom/unzoom of the movie and makes some of my gestures in the overlay view to stop working on the double tap area.

Comment: I got the same issue. Would love to hear an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just add:

```
self.moviePlayerViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Trouble is that prevents any of the embedded controls from working as well which is a shame.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do something like, it works fine for me :) :

```
[[[self.moviePlayer view] subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [[view gestureRecognizers] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id tap, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([tap isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {

            if([tap numberOfTapsRequired]==2)
            {
                [view removeGestureRecognizer:tap];

            }
        }
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Yes ^^
other solutions didn't work for me but this did

Answer (score 1):

The .userInteraction bool will solve the problem, unless you have your own gesture recognizers doing work in the MPMoviePlayerViewController.

If that's the case, then do this instead;

```
self.player.view.gestureRecognizers = nil;
```

Then afterwards, you can add & use your own gesture recognizers, since the interactivity of the player is still yes.